# I want to refresh my list in swiftui view without showing the loading in front end

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui, arraylist, refresh

I have settingsView, HomeView, MapView. From settings view I am calling api to get the list and send it to Home View using binding array. When I am in home view ,my target is to refresh the list so that I can display the updated items on the list view, if any new item will be added from the backend after my api call it should refresh and pull that new item on my existing list without any kind go loading in front end side. Please guide me how to do this. I am very new in swiftui

**MapSwiftUIView**:
here if let userArray = userArray as? [ LiveLocation ]--> userArray is not updating after refresh function is call, In refresh function call I am getting the updated list but in userArray it' not reflecting.-->screenshot attached

**MapViewModel**:here I have added the refresh function to refresh my list, but list is not updating.-->screenshot attached

**HomeViewUI:** From home view I am sending userArray-->screenshot attached

**SettingsSwiftUIView**:This is my settings View, in settings model list view api is calling send sending the data to home view..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuP8I.png)

Comment: struct SettingsSwiftUIView: View {
var body: some View {
            ZStack {
NavigationLink(destination: HomeSwiftUIView(customObjects: $settingsViewModel.userArray), isActive: $settingsViewModel.isHomeActive) {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Settings Done button tapped! : ", $selection)
                            //self.isHomeActive = true
                            ..........

Comment: Instead of an essay based question you should include a Minimal Reproducible Example code is much simpler to follow and a proper example will expose issues easily.